# How to create .mdf and .sha1 file while uploading a file to artifact through curl command

Tags: curl, artifactory

I am using the command below to upload a file to artifact from linux

```
curl -uadmin:password source_path "http://host/artifactory/target_path"
```

but once the file is uploaded .md5 and .sha1 files are not created. When I upload it manually they are created. Can anyone tell me whether I have to pass any parameters or not to the curl command to create .md5 and .sha1 files?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the UI deployment, Artifactory is basically the client and it generates the checksums. Upon using curl, Artifactroy, base on the configuration, will expect the client to provide the md5 and sha1.
In order to make sure that you have the md5 and sha1 files in your repository you can do one of the following:

1. In case using curl - you will need to provide the checksum by sending it.
2. Another option will be to change the repository configuration to calculate the checksum of the file and ignore the client. This can be done by going to Web UI --> Admin --> Local repository --> Edit the desired repository --> and change the 'Checksum Policy' to 'Trust server....'.

The real question here is why do you really need those files for? I mean, artifactory does calculate the checksum for each artifact as this is how it stores the files on the file system. You can also get the calculated checksum on the UI or via rest api, so what is the need?